# Leave Resumption a href not responding in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have this code in Laravel-5.8:

Controller :

```
public function activate_leave_resumption()
{
    $userCompany = Auth::user()->company_id;
    $userEmployee = Auth::user()->employee_id;    
    $userId = Auth::user()->id;
    $leaverequest       = HrLeaveRequest::where('employee_id', $userEmployee)->where('is_resumption_activated', 0)->where('leave_status', 4)->where('resumption_date', '<=', Carbon::now()->toDateString())->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->first();
    $leaverequest->is_resumption_activated          = 1;
    $leaverequest->resumption_activation_date       = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $leaverequest->save();
    Session::flash('success', 'Leave Resumption is Successfully Activated');
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

View :

```
<div class="panel-heading clearfix">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div style="margin-bottom: 10px;" class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <a class="btn btn-info float-right"  href ="{{ route('service.leave_requests.activateLeaveResumption')}}">
                    Resumption Activation
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Route:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'service', 'as' => 'service.', 'namespace' => 'Service', 'middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
    Route::get('service/leave_requests/activate_leave_resumption', 'ServiceLeaveRequestsController@activate_leave_resumption')->name('leave_requests.activateLeaveResumption');
});
```

When Resumption Activation a "href" is submitted, nothing is happening.

No error in the Log and the browser console

How do I rectify this?

Thanks

Comment: you mean when you click on the a tag, it's not going to the controller method??

Comment: @zahidhasanemon - Yes. it redirects back, but no action is perform. It did not submit

Comment: you should get an error. i can see an undefined variable `$userEmployee` in your controller method.

Comment: @zahidhasanemon so it does the roundtrip? How do you pass `$userEmployee` variable to your controller? I assumed you stripped it out for the example.

Comment: @zahidhasanemon - $userEmployee is there. See the updated code. Its from the auth:

Comment: what do you get if you `dd($leaverequest)`??

Comment: @user11352561 I would start debugging the user. I guess it's updating the leave request, but not the one you expect it to. In any other case you would get an exception. By the way, using GET method without checking XSRF token makes it less secure and vulnerable to cross site attacks.

Comment: @ChrisCynarski - How do I achieve this "By the way, using GET method without checking XSRF token makes it less secure and vulnerable to cross site attacks." within the present code

Comment: @zahidhasanemon - I added dd($leaverequest) after   $leaverequest                                   = HrLeaveRequest::where('employee_id', $userEmployee)->where('is_resumption_activated', 0)->where('leave_status', 4)->where('resumption_date', '<=', Carbon::now()->toDateString())->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->first();    but can't see anything

Comment: what do mean by can't see anything?? is it shows the variable is null or there's no dd at all??

Comment: @user11352561 i would change your link to `href="{{ route('service.leave_requests.activateLeaveResumption') }}?token={{ csrf_token() }}"` then you manually check if token is the same as `Session::token()`, or eventually add a token as a part of your route.